# Proving Matrix with exponentials

Tags: matrix-equations

[image]

In the attached question, I was able to make sense of the hint as only the column in a will be changing and the row in b will be changing. I am having trouble visualizing a succinct way to show (B^T)(A^T).

Comment: It's not an exponential, but the matrix transpose

Comment: That would clear it up, thank you!